# How to find Close Button with flutter drive

Tags: flutter, flutterdriver

I am testing a flutter Cupertino styled app using flutter drive.

I have trouble closing a full-screen page because I cannot find the close button.

What would be the correct `find.by???` instruction to be able to tap the close button in a
Cupertino styled app?

Comment: Is this page routed using Navigator.push?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's pushNamed

Comment: just call Navigator.pop(); to close the full screen and return to previous screen

Comment: How can I "just" call Navigator.pop()? I am in flutter drive, I am out of process and have no Navigator object.

Comment: Better show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find.pageBack()` like in `await driver.tap(find.pageBack());` to find the button that has the page back functionality, either a back arrow or a close cross, if present in the AppBar.

Alternatively you can use directly `find.byTooltip('Back')` or `find.byTooltip('Close')` to find back arrows or close buttons.